# Integrating Gstreamer Camera Output window and Qml window

Tags: linux, qml, gstreamer, qt5.5

I am trying to create a qml application in Qt 5.5 to stream the camera output using **Gstreamer 1.0** libraries (Not the existing Qml Camera). Now I am getting the gstreamer output and application window as seperate windows. **How can I integrate gstreamer camera output window to Qml window ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [To connect Gstreamer with Qt in order to play a gstreamer video in the Qt Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250169/to-connect-gstreamer-with-qt-in-order-to-play-a-gstreamer-video-in-the-qt-widget)

Comment: See also http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html

Comment: @g-v This is not a duplicate of [To connect Gstreamer with Qt in order to play a gstreamer video in the Qt Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250169/to-connect-gstreamer-with-qt-in-order-to-play-a-gstreamer-video-in-the-qt-widget) . I have already done that. But the issue here is the Qml integration of that widget. Means I need the gstreamer output in Qml window.

Comment: @g-v I tried QtGstreamer earlier in Desktop. I need this application in IMX also. I think Crosscompiling QtGstreamer to target is very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This is more some kind of set of ideas than actual answer, but maybe it will get you in (hopefully good, or at least some) direction.

I think that crosscompiling just gstreamer (if you do not have it already) will suffice.

You can easily use gstreamer from your Qt application. Next thing to do is to implement the pipeline you already have inside your Qt app (make a class for that etc) with appsink instead of ximagesink or whatever you use now.

Then you just get the frames out of appsink and push them into some QML widget.
I dont know which element that would be..

but [here](http://blogs.igalia.com/xrcalvar/2012/04/29/painting-video-with-gstreamer-and-qtqml-or-gtk-with-overlay/)  and [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/examples_2qmlplayer_2main_8cpp-example.html) I found some examples (the second uses QtGstreamer but it has some useful insights).

I think (but just speculating, never done that) you could set viewport of QDeclarativeItem to QGLWidget. Then it is a matter of painting the frames with the QPainter.

I think there is also some way how to just pass OpenGL context and paint directly..

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I will check it and comeback

Comment: @VishnuLALK  am just reading that in now released [gstreamer 1.6](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2015-September/054726.html) there is some new sink for QML elements, this may be very interesting for you..